Trying to make a tree containing every english word, but only one word is showing up in the tree
also if you have any criticisms please share.
the search function does a depth first search throughout the tree but it's showing connections as null pointers that I've checked weren't null in the while loop in the main function that creates the tree. This results in the last word in the word bank to be the only word present in the tree.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ALPHSIZE 26
#define WORDBANKNAME "testwordbank.txt"

int hashy(int c){
    return (int) c-97;
};

struct Node{
    bool end;   
    char c;
    struct Node** connections;
};

void search(struct Node* head,int depth){
    depth++;
    for(int i = 0; i < ALPHSIZE; i++){
        printf("depth %i checking %c = %p\n",depth,i+97,head->connections[i]);
        if (head->connections[i]){
            if(head->connections[i]->end) printf("end!!: ");
            printf("%c\n",head->connections[i]->c);
            search(head->connections[i],depth);
        }
    }
};

struct Node* createNode(char c) {
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->end = false;
    newNode->c = c;
    newNode->connections = malloc(ALPHSIZE*sizeof(struct Node*));
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHSIZE; i++) {
        newNode->connections[i] = NULL;
    }
    return newNode;
}


int main(){
    FILE* wordbank = fopen(WORDBANKNAME,"r");
    struct Node*root = createNode((char)1);
    
    struct Node* head = root;
    int nextchar = getc(wordbank);
    
  
    while(nextchar != EOF){
        if (nextchar == '\n'){
            head->end = true; 
            head = root;
            nextchar = getc(wordbank);
            continue;
        }
        int cindex = hashy(nextchar);
        head->connections[cindex] = createNode(nextchar);
        head = head->connections[cindex];
        nextchar = getc(wordbank);
    }
    printf("-----------\n");
    search(root,0);

    fclose(wordbank);
    return 0;
};

I think it might be a problem with overwriting/allocating in use memory.

What does stepping through the code in the debugger tell you?

Please edit question and supply (small) wordlist and the output you are getting from your program on that wordlist.

I revised your question to remove the sentence where you describe the language, we use tags for that, and the self-disparaging language.  Your code is fine you just need to put a little effort into troubleshooting.  That will come with experience.

OT: Every node will also have 26 pointers allocated. There's no advantage in using two invocations of malloc(). Code would be simpler if connections was an array instead of a ptr-to-ptrs...
